# Decide whether each map is an isomorphism( if it is an isomorphism then prove it)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

[image: so this is the question I am having]

my problem is that i dont uderstand how they got the matrix for onto: f: M_2x2 --> P_3 can someone explains please?

[image: this is the answeer to the question]

Comment: It is very hard to read a question like this. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a tutorial on how to use Latex to write neat equations.

Comment: thanks was looking for that

Comment: Set $f(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix})=p+qx+rx^2+sx^3$, expand out the left side, equate coefficients, solve for $a,b,c,d$ in terms of $p,q,r,s$.

Comment: I did that but how do I expand it in term of p,q,r,s ?